# JavaScript: copy text AND image to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, web, clipboard

I've got a fairly straightforward requirement to implement - a button on a webpage which will copy a block of text with an image in it to the clipboard.

I do know how to copy text and I know how to copy an image. As far as I can tell, I can't do both. Am I missing something or is it indeed not possible with JavaScript? Can anyone think of any alternative solution (I'd say Flash it it was 1995 :-) ).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by combining the [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) and [`Range/Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) functionality:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#copy-button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  let container = document.querySelector('.container');

  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    selection.removeAllRanges();
  }
  
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(container);
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  selection.removeAllRanges();
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button id="copy-button">copy</button>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://moview.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Mountain_RvB-3-bw.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The execCommand() Is obsolete -  but I think it will have to do as I can think of no other solution ...

Comment: You can always move to the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard), but browser support might be a bit finnicky.

Comment: Well, I do use Clipboard API, but I don't think it allows to copy both text and images. And if you could, it's unlikely it would work in all browsers.

Comment: Clipboard API has drawbacks: to copy text & images we must use: "text/html" MIME type, but when using this type, it's not possible to paste the content into Notepad for some reason. Somehow the obsolete `execCommand` allows copying both text & images, and using it Notepad knows how to only take the text out of it.